# Adding Null observations (rows) within a Dataset when a comparison condition is met

Tags: merge, sas, data-manipulation

I have pairs of datasets (A & B), but A always has extra observations that were completely removed in B which causes me to lose the original value of the variable "Seg" in B.

Example:

```
Dataset A             Dataset B               Desired dataset C:

Seg    Fz             Seg    Fz               Seg    Fz

 1     2.3            1     2.3               1    2.3
 2     9.2            2     1.3               2    .
 3     1.3            3     0.9               3    1.3
 4     11.4                                   4    .
 5     0.9                                    5    0.9
```

I need to merge the 2 datasets (A & B) into 1 (C), and replace the extra observations for A with missing values to keep the order of the "Seg" variable and get the desired dataset C.

Is there an easy way to do this?
I have 300 pairs of dataset each containing 44 observations and 4 variables,
so i plan to incorporate this into a macro or a do loop.

thank you :)

sample code:

```
data A;
input Seg Fz;
datalines;
 1     2.3                           
 2     9.2                          
 3     1.3                           
 4     11.4                               
 5     0.9                                   
run;


data B;
input Seg Fz;
datalines;
1     2.3              
2     1.3               
3     0.9                                                                                
run;
```

Comment: Can you explain how to determine which value to keep in dataset C? Like why is seg 4 missing but seg 3 1.3?

Comment: in dataset c why is seg 2 missing but seg 3 1.3 and why is seg 4 missing but seg 5 .9?

Comment: I'll explain @superfluous. This data comes from clinical experiment with patients. The observations that were removed (by a third party) in dataset A were considered as being biased because of interference. But because i'm working with longitudinal data and trying to correctly model the correlation structure, the order of the data as well as the missing observations are of high importance to me.

Comment: That doesn't answer either question asked.

Comment: @DCR sorry. i'll try to make myself clearer. The observations to keep are the ones in dataset B. So any observation that is contained in A but not in B is to be replaced by a null value. While preserving the values of the "Seg" variable from A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you what you are looking.

```
proc sql noprint;
     create table c as
            select a.seg,b.fz 
                   from a as a
            left join b as b
            on a.fz=b.fz
            order by a.seg;
quit;
```

but be carefull, if either dataset a or b can have duplicate values this may not give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! @DCR, its works !!!! I don't think duplicates are possible with my data. The original numbers have 8 digits after the decimal. (i.e. 3.72346857) So its highly unlikely. But of course, i am going to  manually add duplicates and test just to see and also to get a good understanding of what those 8 lines of code do. LONG LIVE PROC SQL !!! :)